# Why isn't pyenv finding openssl shared libraries under Alpine Linux?

Tags: python, linux, docker, pyenv, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build a docker image from `gliderlabs/alpine:latest` containing only pyenv and it's dependencies.  I would like for this container to be able to install and execute an arbitrary interpreter through pyenv.

## Initial Attempt

I began with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:latest

RUN apk-install curl \
  ca-certificates \
  bash \
  git \
  openssl-dev \
  readline-dev \
  bzip2-dev \
  sqlite-dev \
  build-base

RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer -o /pyenv-installer
RUN touch /root/.bashrc && \
      /bin/ln -s /root/.bashrc /root/.bash_profile && \
      /bin/bash /pyenv-installer && \
      rm /pyenv-installer && \
      echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile && \
      echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile && \
      echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

ENV HOME  /root
ENV PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
ENV PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
```

## The Error

Once built, I can start a container and run bash, and the `pyenv` command is available, as expected.

However, when I try to run `pyenv install 3.4.3` I get the following error:

```
bash-4.3# pyenv install 3.4.3
Downloading Python-3.4.3.tgz...
-> https://yyuu.github.io/pythons/4281ff86778db65892c05151d5de738d
Installing Python-3.4.3...
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (Alpine Linux 3.2.3 using python-build 20151006)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20151006155321.99
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20151006155321.99.log

Last 10 log lines:
(cd /root/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/share/man/man1; ln -s python3.4.1 python3.1)
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
    case upgrade in \
        upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
     ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 6.0.8 requires SSL/TLS
```

## Attempted Fix

After a bit of googling I found [this](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems) page, which, for OSX/homebrew, suggests the following fix:

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include"
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib"
```

Since I'm not using OSX or Homebrew, I attempted to adapt these commands to an Alpine environment by adding the following lines to the Dockerfile:

```
ENV CFLAGS '-I/usr/include'
ENV LDFLAGS '-L/usr/lib'
```

Please note that `/usr/lib` contains:

- `libssl.a`
- `libssl.so`
- `libssl.so.1.0.0`

and `/usr/include` contains `openssl`.  This having been said, the modification seems to have no impact on my error when installing Python 3.4.3.

## The Question

How can I get pyenv to install a python environment under a dockerized Alpine Linux?

### Edit:

1. The pyenv [build log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12697917/) is apparently chocking because the `sockaddr_can` type is undefined.  I'm officially lost.  Is this a `musl` bug ?

Comment: Long time I haven't seen a well constructed question with real background research :D. 
Could you provide the result of your docker run ? Especially the result of `pyenv-installer` installation.

Comment: @Cyrbil:  Thanks!  [here](https://gist.github.com/lthibault/253ebcf4b93f311851e0) is the output to `docker build -t test/alpine.pyenv alpine.pyenv/ `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem had to do with `musl` not finding generic linux headers.  The solution is to install `linux-headers`.

Below is a minimal working Dockerfile:

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:latest

RUN apk-install curl \
      ca-certificates \
      bash \
      git \
      openssl-dev \
      readline-dev \
      bzip2-dev \
      sqlite-dev \
      ncurses-dev \
      linux-headers \
      build-base

RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer -o /pyenv-installer && \
      touch /root/.bashrc && \
      /bin/ln -s /root/.bashrc /root/.bash_profile && \
      /bin/bash /pyenv-installer && \
      rm /pyenv-installer && \
      echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile && \
      echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile && \
      echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

ENV HOME  /root
ENV PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
ENV PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: If it's working maybe you should document it for others to find. Also add the Linux headers dependency to pyenv-doctor.

Comment: @the_drow, Any suggestions on where to document this solution?

Comment: Add it to the common build problems page I linked.

Comment: Great! I'm happy if you added some tips on musl on Alpine Linux to some of pyenv's wiki page. As @the_drow mentioned, https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#requirements would be the best place.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that the problem here is that you don't have the headers and you need to install them.
Just add `apk add openssl-dev` to your Dockerfile.

Try running pyenv doctor in your container and see if you have all the required dependencies installed.
Also see https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#requirements for the required packages and try to find the right equivalents for Alpine Linux. While you're at it, add those to the documentation so others will be able to find it.

Comment: I'm upvoting because your (since redacted) suggestion to run `pyenv doctor` allowed me to include some missing system libraries (see edited Dockerfile).  However, I'm still getting the same OpenSSL error as before.

Comment: In that case I think you should try to find where the headers are installed. Try to use find or locate. They might be installed elsewhere.

Comment: they seem to be in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` (see main question).  I'm not sure what I should be looking for, exactly, though.

Comment: Type locate openssl and see if you can find the headers under /usr/include. If they aren't you'll have to run locate from root.

Comment: I don't seem to have access to the `locate` command, nor can I figure out how to install it.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: What about find? Can you install that?

Comment: this apprears to be a `musl` problem.  Please see my edits, if you have a chance.  Maybe you have an idea?